# Show that $c(G)\geq |V|-|E|$, where the equality holds iff $G$ is cycless.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $c(G)$ denote the number of connected components of a graph $G$.
I am asked

> Let $G=(V,E)$. Show that $c(G)\geq |V|-|E|$, where the equality holds iff $G$ is cycless.

If I'm understanding the question correctly, we want to show the inequality $$c(G)>|V|-|E|$$
holds if G contains a cycle. Then prove that 
$$c(G)=|V|-|E|$$
iff G is cycleless.

Is this the correct interpretation of the question? 
Would proving either the inequality or the equality make the other a simpler case of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little long for a comment, so I'm adding this as an answer.

You are being asked to show two things. First: $c(G) \geq |V| - |E|$. Second, $c(G) = |V| - |E|$ iff $c(G)$ contains no cycles (i.e., $G$ is a forest).

You may find the following fact useful. Let $G$ be a connected graph on $|V|$ vertices. $G$ does not contain a cycle iff $|E| = |V| - 1$.

Now suppose $G$ is a forest. What can you say about each component $C$'s vertices and edges? Can you use that to count the number of connected components?

Now what happens if you add an edge to a graph without a cycle? Consider two cases: you connect two disconnected components, or both endpoints are on the same component.

Do you see what is going on?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use that lemma, since it was provided as a corollary to what we're trying to show here. If G is a forest, then every connected component is a tree, which is cycleless by definition. If we connect two disconnected components, then the connected components decrease and the number of edges increase. Is that a fair assessment of what we have so far? Just trying to work out my confusion.

Comment: So if I have two connected components and add an edge between then, then $c(G + e) = c(G) - 1 = |V(G)| - (|E(G)| + 1) = |V(G + e)| - |E(G + e)|$.